# Creating new entries in SQL Server from Android app

Tags: android, sql-server, json, wcf

I am currently working on an app that enters information into my JobStatus table. Essentially, this ASyncTask should run when the mSign button is clicked. However, I keep getting the same errors. I am guessing that it may have to do with what I'm using as a parameter in invoking the AsyncTask.

Based on experience, has anyone used an AsyncTask to enter information from an Android app into an SQL Server database? What would be considered an "acceptable" parameter used by the ASyncTask in HTTPPost instances like these?

Is there something that I'm missing here? I've implemented HttpGet before, but I'm pretty new to the whole HttpPost and AsyncTask, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks again everyone. :)

```
05-31 14:11:51.029: E/WindowManager(9545): Activity com.signonglass.CaptureSignature has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4178f590 that was originally added here
05-31 14:11:51.029: E/WindowManager(9545): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.signonglass.CaptureSignature has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4178f590 that was originally added here
05-31 14:11:51.029: E/WindowManager(9545):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:363)
05-31 14:11:51.029: E/WindowManager(9545):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:268)
05-31 14:11:51.029: E/WindowManager(9545):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:216)
05-31 14:11:51.029: E/WindowManager(9545):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:141)
05-31 14:11:51.029: E/WindowManager(9545):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
05-31 14:11:51.029: E/WindowManager(9545):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:278)
05-31 14:11:51.029: E/WindowManager(9545):  at com.signonglass.CaptureSignature$updateJobStatus.onPreExecute(CaptureSignature.java:210)
05-31 14:11:51.029: E/WindowManager(9545):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:561)
05-31 14:11:51.029: E/WindowManager(9545):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:511)
05-31 14:11:51.029: E/WindowManager(9545):  at com.signonglass.CaptureSignature$2.onClick(CaptureSignature.java:169)
05-31 14:11:51.029: E/WindowManager(9545):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3517)
05-31 14:11:51.029: E/WindowManager(9545):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14155)
05-31 14:11:51.029: E/WindowManager(9545):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
05-31 14:11:51.029: E/WindowManager(9545):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-31 14:11:51.029: E/WindowManager(9545):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
05-31 14:11:51.029: E/WindowManager(9545):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
05-31 14:11:51.029: E/WindowManager(9545):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-31 14:11:51.029: E/WindowManager(9545):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-31 14:11:51.029: E/WindowManager(9545):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
05-31 14:11:51.029: E/WindowManager(9545):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
05-31 14:11:51.029: E/WindowManager(9545):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here are some key things about my AsyncTask:-

```
private final static String jobURI = "http://192.168.0.105:8095/CentralMonitoring/CentralMonitor.svc/addJobStatus/";
```

WCF Interface:

```
 [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "addJobStatus")]
        wsSQLResult AddJobStatus(Stream JSONdataStream);
```

WCF Service: (I've tested this using Fiddler, and it works fine).

```
public wsSQLResult AddJobStatus(Stream JSONdataStream)
        {
            wsSQLResult result = new wsSQLResult();
            try
            {
                // Read in our Stream into a string...
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(JSONdataStream);
                string JSONdata = reader.ReadToEnd();

                // ..then convert the string into a single "wsCustomer" record.
                JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                JobStatusObj jso = jss.Deserialize<JobStatusObj>(JSONdata);

                if (jso == null)
                {
                    result.WasSuccessful = 0;
                    result.Exception = "Unable to deserialize the JSON data.";
                }
                else
                {
                    CentralMonitoringDataContext cdc = new CentralMonitoringDataContext();
                    JobStatus js = new JobStatus()
                    {
                        JobStatusID = jso.JobStatusID,
                        JobType = jso.jobType,
                        QLSJobID = jso.qlsJobID,
                        DateComplete = DateTime.Parse(jso.dateComplete),
                        TimeComplete = DateTime.Parse(jso.timeComplete),
                        Latitude = Convert.ToDecimal(jso.latitude),
                        Longitude = Convert.ToDecimal(jso.longitude),
                        RecipientName = jso.recipientName
                    };

                    if (!cdc.JobStatus.Any(cj => cj.QLSJobID == jso.qlsJobID))
                    {
                        cdc.JobStatus.InsertOnSubmit(js);
                        cdc.SubmitChanges();

                        result.WasSuccessful = 1;
                        result.Exception = "";
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result.WasSuccessful = 0;
                result.Exception = ex.Message;
            }
            return result;
        }  
    }
```

Finally, here is the code of the AsyncTask:

```
public class addJobStatus extends AsyncTask<JobStatus, Void, Void>
    {
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(CaptureSignature.this);
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        StringBuilder builder;


        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            progressDialog.setMessage("Updating " + uniqueId +"...");
            progressDialog.show();
            progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener()
            {
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0)
                {
                    addJobStatus.this.cancel(true);

                }
            });     
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(JobStatus... arg0)
        {
            try
            {
                JSONObject js = new JSONObject();
                js.put("jobType", cObj.getJobType());
                js.put("qlsJobID", cObj.getConsignmentID());
                js.put("dateComplete", sdf.format(currentTime));
                js.put("timeComplete", sdf.format(currentTime));
                js.put("latitude", location.getLatitude());
                js.put("longitude", location.getLongitude());
                js.put("recipientName", yourName.getText().toString());

                JSONArray jsArray = new JSONArray();
                jsArray.put(js);

                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("addJobStatus", jsArray.toString()));
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost request = new HttpPost(jobURI);
                request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                //StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsArray.toString(), "UTF-8");

                request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8));
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                inputStream = entity.getContent();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused)
        {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Value updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }



    }
```

I intend to call the AsyncTask here at this point:-

```
mGetSign.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {        
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Log.v("log_tag", "Panel Saved");
                boolean error = captureSignature();
                if(!error)
                {
                    //initialise new jobStatus object here.
                    new addJobStatus().execute(js);
                    mView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                    mSignature.save(mView);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putString("status", "done");
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.putExtras(b);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
                    finish(); 
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the parameters that are causing the problem. It is nothing related to HTTP at all :-)

The problem is that after you start your async task, you are finishing your activity with a `finish()` call.

This is causing the Async task `progressDialog.show()` call to fail since there is no Activity for it to display the dialog on!

If you must finish your activity after the Async task, then do it in the onPostExecute() method of the Async task after you have dismissed your dialog. This will ensure that there are no Window leak errors like the ones you are getting now.

Comment: Sweet. I missed that out. :O. Let me check this out.

Comment: Hey bro... I tried it. No errors in the log, but nothing is still going into the Database. Could it be the return types in the Asynctask maybe?

Comment: don't think it has anything to do with return types since you are not using them. Since you are sending data to your server, you should check whether data is being transferred properly and then check your server side code to see if it is being accurately received and updated in the database.

Comment: I fixed it. It was the URL. It had an "/" at the end of the URL. It's not misbehaving any more. That's for sure. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With @Anup's help, I got around the problem. Here I believe, were the problems, to begin with:-

1. There was no Array declaration in the WCF service. So I took out the JSONArray in my AsyncTask.
2. I took the "/" out of the URI.
3. As suggested to me, the "finish()" method that @Anup mentioned.

Entries are now going into the DB like no tomorrow. :)

Even though this has been sorted, I'm still giving @Anup for the heads up first. :)